# Php. ошибка в связке. синтаксис

Tags: php, denwer

помогите найти ошибку. сам код должен выполнять сортировку строк

```
<?php 
        function string_sort($a, $b)
    {if (strlen($a) < strlen($b)){ return 1; }
      elseif (strlen($a) == strlen($b)){ return 0; } 
       else { return -1; }}

        $arr = array();
        for($i=0;$i<9;$i++)
        {
        $arr[]=($_POST[in.$i]); // // ошибка где-то тут
        }
        usort($arr, 'string_sort');

        for($i=0;$i<9;$i++)
        {
    // ошибка где-то тут
        echo (' <input type="text" name="in.$i." value="$arr['.$i.']"> <br>' ); 
// ошибка где-то тут
        }   
        ?>

        <input type="submit" name="OK" value="OKDA">
```

Comment: $_POST[in.$i] что это? конкретней... PHP 4? в строку оберните

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ('<input type="text" name="in' . $i . '" value="' . $arr[$i] . '"><br>');
```